# Power Series Without Differentiating

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series

As the title suggests, I want to find a way to show that for $|x|<1: $ \begin{equation}
S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}=\ln\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}\bigg) \end{equation}   without taking the derivative of the power series, or any calculus. I have tried for several hours and gotten nowhere. I've mainly tried transforming the equation into something of the form $S(x-1)$ which gives us \begin{equation} 
S=\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac {n\cdot x^n}{(n-1)\cdot (x-1)}  - \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1) \cdot x^n}{n\cdot (x-1)} - 1 -\frac 1{x-1} \end{equation}
Don't really know how useful this is (if I haven't messed up my algebra). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The geometric series converges for $|x| < 1$, which is given by
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n} = 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align*}
If we integrate both sides (which is possible due to the properties of real-analytic functions), one gets that
\begin{align*}
\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = -\ln(1-x)= \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1-z} = x + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n} 
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I was asking more for a proof without any calculus at all, just using normal series techniques. Thanks for this elegant proof though.

Comment: You  can't hope to have the power series expansion for transcendental function without any calculus.

Comment: @Bernard Could you give more detail (maybe even a nice proof) why this is completely out of reach?

Comment: Well, intuitively, a power series obtainable by purely algebraic methods can only be an algebraic function.

Comment: @Bernard I see what you mean, but the fact is that power series are in and of themselves algebraic sums, which we can permute etc... So I thought it would seem reasonable to try and find an algebraic approach that gets us to, or very close to, $-ln(1-x)$. Also, I did not ban the use of the exponential function, which I think may be a promising avenue to explore, if one can find some way to compose this power series and $e^x$ intelligently.

Comment: The algebraic part is *formal power series* ( for which no notion of convergence is attached).

Comment: +1 for the answer and the nice points you have raised in comments (algebra can manage only the formal power series and algebraic functions).